# Removing everything after a certain character

Tags: php, strings, url

I was just writing code, and wanted to make a piece that removes everything after the character `?` if it's found within the URL.

```
if (strstr($url, "?")) {
    $url = strstr($url, "?", true);
}
```

Can I make this any shorter? It doesn't feel right to type the "same thing" twice with `strstr`.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the same variable for two different purpose. It would be readable with separate variables:

```
$urlWithoutParameters = strstr($url, "?", true); 
if ($urlWithoutParameters !== FALSE) {
    // if you need additional processing
}
```

It might be safer to use PHP's built-in [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) function which could help handling invalid inputs too:

> On seriously malformed URLs, `parse_url()` may return `FALSE`.

From *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries*:

> By using a standard library,
>   you take advantage of the knowledge of the experts who wrote it and the
>   experience of those who used it before you.

(It's mostly a Java book but it applies here.)

Answer (score 4):

Doing a quick test, as follows, shows that using `explode()` is about 4 times as fast as calling strstr() twice.

```
$url = "http://google.com/test.php?somevar=laksd";
$url2 = "http://google.com/test.php?somevar=laksd";

$start = microtime();
for($i = 0; $i <= 2000000; $i++){
  if (strstr($url, "?")) {
    $url = strstr($url, "?", true);
  }
}
$end = microtime();

echo "took " . ($end - $start) . "<br>";

$start = microtime();
for($i = 0; $i <= 2000000; $i++){
  $url = explode("?", $url2);
  $url = $url[0];
}
$end = microtime();

echo "took " . ($end - $start) . "<br>";

print_r($url);
```

The output is as follows:

```
2000000 iterations of strstr took 0.573858
2000000 iterations of explode took 0.132764
http://google.com/test.php
```

However, unless you have hundreds of millions of visitors to your site, you don't have to hyper optimize this way. If its purely from an aesthetic point of view, then I would say just do:

```
$url = explode("?", $url);
$url = $url[0];
```

In PHP 5.4 and greater, you can access the array element directly (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88):

```
$url = explode("?", $url)[0];
```